# mysql return single row and status for multiple rows

Tags: mysql

apologies for vague question title but not sure on correct wording, please correct if need be.

I have the following MySQL query which joins several of my tables together.

```
select distinct(o.person), 
    o.job,
    p.risk,
    r.training,
    case when c.datecompleted  is null then 'no' else 'yes' end TrainingCompleted,
    case when c.expirydate is null then '' else c.expirydate end expirydate
from 
    orgstructure o 
    join personrisks p on p.Person=o.person
    right outer join risktraining r on r.risk=p.risk
    left outer join coursescompleted c on c.course=r.training and c.person=o.person
where o.department='house keeping' and o.person <> ''
order by o.person desc
```

it produces the below result:

[image]

in the result, you can see that each risk has two training solutions that address the risk. I want to return another column `status` that looks to each training and training completed field, if either of the training is completed then status `good` else status `bad`. so my output will only have two rows in this example for each risk. should none of the training have been completed then show any `training` value as being needed.

ideal output:

[image]

How do I edit this query to achieve the desired results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way to do it is

```
select 
    o.person,
    o.job,
    p.risk,
    case when count(c.datecompleted) > 0 then null else r.training end as training,
    case when count(c.datecompleted) > 0 then 'yes' else 'no' end as TrainingCompleted,
    case when count(c.datecompleted) > 0 then 'good' else 'bad' end as Status
from orgstructure o 
    join personrisks p on p.Person=o.person
    right outer join risktraining r on r.risk=p.risk
    left outer join coursescompleted c on c.course=r.training and c.person=o.person
where o.department='house keeping' and o.person <> ''
group by o.person
order by o.person desc, case when c.datecompleted is not null then 0 else 1 end asc
```

Here I do not showing training if either of traning is completed.

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0035a/2)